# how to change the color of an icon after the page loads using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, icons

I have an icon that i want to change the color after document loads to indicate that the user has that particular item in the database.

HTML

```
<li>
  <div class="bookmark">
      <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
  </div>
</li>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
 const bookmark = document.querySelector('.fa-bookmark')


$(document).on('load', '.bookmark', (event) => {
    console.log("in jquery function")
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
    
   

    if (user) {//if user is signed in
          bookmark.classList.add('amber-text');
    }

});
```

When the document loads, I want the event listener to change the color if the item is in the users database. But for some reason, this isn't working. Im not sure if i am using the right event. The same code works if I use a click event instead of load.

Comment: try to see what contains `user`, maybe you are retrieving the wrong object

Comment: user  = true. So the same code works if I use a click event instead of load. I am not sure why that is the case.

Comment: try using `$(document).ready(()=>{})` no?

Comment: This solution worked. thanks

Comment: i've posted a answer, if you don't mind, mark it as correct to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    ...
})
```